# How to prevent SQL Server Job History deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, deadlock, jobs

Out of the ~50 instances I currently manage, I have two that each have one deadlock almost every night involving "INSERT INTO msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory" (always the victim) and "DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory" called by "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_purge_jobhistory", both sessions run by the SQL Server Agent service account. I have never had such a deadlock on any of the other instances, nor at any previous jobs. One each of these servers, the deadlocks occur at different times during the night (1:30 Saturdays run by a weekly schedule for sp_purge_jobhistory or 2:01 run by a step in the nightly schedule for syspolicy_purge_history).

There doesn't seem to be anything significantly different between these two "problem" instances and any of the others. One is a 2012 SP3 CU3 test server and the other is 2012 SP2 production instance.

Any ideas as to how I can prevent this?

Comment: Try rescheduling syspolicy_purge_history?

Comment: It runs on the same schedule on all servers. Many of the servers (including these two) have jobs that run every 10 or every 30 seconds. I'm as curious as to why I don't have this problem everywhere else as I am about why I have it on these two. :-)

Comment: Your question was "how can I prevent this?" -- don't think anyone can tell you why it's happening with the just the information you provided.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik: Sadly, you may be right about that. But I have hope that someone will at least come up with a good question that would lead to a discovery.

Comment: Cool, best of luck!

Comment: To me, this sounds like you have a Maintenance Plan (History Cleanup Task) that runs as a Sql Agent job (scanning) and is colliding with a normal backup job (Full, Diff, Log) trying to insert a new row.  Is the history retention the same between all of your instances.  Are any of your Sql Agent jobs failing.  How long are these types of jobs (cleanup, backup) running on the various servers.  While not a solution, there's always incrementing 'Retry' on a failing job step.

Comment: @ScottHodgin: Great question! No jobs are failing. The victim is being run by "SQLAgent - Job Manager" and the other other process is either "CMD" (the weekly job on Saturdays) or "SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep" (the nightly job). But there may be one that is retrying at that time. I'll go hunting through the logs...

Comment: I experienced similar issue with servers had many jobs running at short (one or two minute) interval and history retention long.  Few actions resolved my issue. 1. custom history retention. 2. run purge more frequently (not once a week).

Comment: @Taiob: Good thought. Keeping 30 days of job history on servers with jobs running as often as 10 seconds makes for long execution of the sp_purge_jobhistory, even when run nightly. I got rid of Ola's sp_purge_jobhistory job (redundant with my customized syspolicy_purge_history anyway) and will gradually decrease the retention days on the job history until, hopefully, the deadlocks stop.

Comment: @Mark This might help you. http://sqlworldwide.com/manage-sql-agent-job-history/

Comment: @Taiob: Great find! With our current 30 day retention, we have 529,218 rows fo history for the job that runs every 10 seconds, out of a total of 870,662 rows. Putting in place a mechanism to have different retention policies for different jobs (or just for success vs. failure) would probably make a big difference in how long that delete takes every night on these instances that have little memory and slow disks.

Comment: Please mark the comments if those were helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this (a much simplified version of the code in @Taiob's blog post he linked to), and then call it from a job instead of the Microsoft-provided sp_purge_jobhistory:

```
--  Create Procedure PurgeJobHistory.sql

USE master;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.procedures p JOIN sys.schemas s ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id WHERE s.name = N'dbo' AND p.name = N'PurgeJobHistory') BEGIN
   EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PurgeJobHistory] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END');
END;
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PurgeJobHistory]
    @numberOfDaysToKeepSucceeded    SMALLINT    =   7
    ,@numberOfDaysToKeepOther       SMALLINT    =   30
AS
/*
Purpose:        Purges old rows from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory, providing for different retention for success vs. other statuses
Author:         Mark Freeman (@m60freeman)
Last Edited:    2017-03-29
Compatibility:  SQL Server 2008 and newer
Adapted from:   http://sqlworldwide.com/manage-sql-agent-job-history/
License:        This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.
                    http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/
*/
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;

DECLARE @LastDateToRetainSucceeded  INT
        ,@LastDateToRetainOther     INT
        ,@RowsDeleted               INT
        ,@RowCount                  INT;

--Get the actual date of the most recent rows that we wish to maintain (converted match sysjobhistory.run_date)
SELECT  @LastDateToRetainSucceeded  = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), (GETDATE() - @numberOfDaysToKeepSucceeded), 112))
        ,@LastDateToRetainOther     = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), (GETDATE() - @numberOfDaysToKeepOther), 112))
        ,@RowCount                  = COUNT(1)
  FROM  msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sjh WITH (NOLOCK);

RAISERROR('Starting rows in history: %i', 0, 1, @RowCount) WITH NOWAIT;

--DELETE sysjobhistory rows 1,000 at a time in a loop until we have nothing left to delete
SET @RowsDeleted = -1;

WHILE @RowsDeleted != 0 BEGIN
    --Handle rows with a Succeeded status
    BEGIN TRAN;
        DELETE  TOP (1000)
          FROM  msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory WITH (READPAST)      --Ignore locked rows
         WHERE  run_status  =   1                           --Succeeded
           AND  run_date    <   @LastDateToRetainSucceeded;

        SELECT  @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
        RAISERROR('Succeeded rows deleted: %i', 0, 1, @RowsDeleted) WITH NOWAIT;
    COMMIT;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
END;

SET @RowsDeleted = 1;

WHILE @RowsDeleted != 0 BEGIN
    --Handle rows with all other status values
    BEGIN TRAN;
        DELETE  TOP (1000)
          FROM  msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory WITH (READPAST)      --Ignore locked rows
         WHERE  run_status  IN  (0, 2, 3)                   --Failed, Retry, and Canceled are all treated as failures.
           AND  run_date    <   @LastDateToRetainOther;

        SELECT  @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
        RAISERROR('Other rows deleted:     %i', 0, 1, @RowsDeleted) WITH NOWAIT;
    COMMIT;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
END;

SELECT  @RowCount   = COUNT(1)
  FROM  msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sjh WITH (NOLOCK);

RAISERROR('Ending rows in history: %i', 0, 1, @RowCount) WITH NOWAIT;
GO
```

It cut us down from having over 1 million rows in msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory to only about 1/4 as many, and the deletes are no longer involved in deadlocks.

Thanks to @Taiob and @ScottHodgin for their input!